# Meaning of "span" in this sentence?

Tags: meaning

Reading this article I could not figure out the meaning the word *span* should have in the following snippet. What does the author mean by *span of branches*? I'm not a native speaker.

> Pirk et. al. (Pirk et al., 2012) noted that one of the drawbacks of
> the Space Colonization technique is the need to regrow the entire tree
> structure to adapt to changing external factors. In their approach,
> they instead take a fully formed tree skeleton as the base model and
> compute its method of growth. In doing this they have the total
> **span** of branches that could possibly be created and so can adapt the tree to varying surroundings. Their system provides visually
> pleasing results, however their system is still locked into the set of
> branches that are initially provided and adding more is not possible.

Comment: It sounds like "span" is a technical term used when discussing "tree structures".  So, you would look in a computer science textbook where tree structures are done, and see the definition of "span" there.

Comment: The total number of child nodes at the ends (bottom) of all branches form the span ... the width of branch ends.

Comment: Cambridge dictionary has span = the length of something from one end to the other. The width of the tree. This should have been a dictionary exercise for you.